# How to upload images with Rails-Api + Vue.js + Cloudinary + Attachinary?

Tags: vue.js, cloudinary, rails-api

With server rendered rails apps I've always used cloudinary and attachinary to upload images and other files to a third party server and have them linked to my data models.

I am now increasingly using Vue.js with Rails-Api, and I'm wondering if I can still use Attachinary + Cloudinary, and how? What would be the simplest approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudinary doesn't support an official Vue.js integration yet. You can try and implement the [cloudinary-core package](https://github.com/cloudinary/pkg-cloudinary-core/blob/master/cloudinary-core.js) (pure js package) in your project.